# Which solver is suitable for bilevel problems, CPLEX or Gurobi?

Tags: optimization, solver, cplex, gurobi

I am trying to model a bi-level problem using a solver.

I wonder about CPLEX and Gurobi: which one is the best choice? Based on my research, there is no important difference between these two, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily find benchmark tests that compare CPLEX and Gurobi
Some of those benchmarks argue that CPLEX is better than Gurobi, while others affirm that Gurobi has a better performance than CPLEX.

Therefore, we can conclude that both solvers have **similar** performances when solving Mixed-Integer Linear Programming problems (as is the case of your bilevel optimization problem), see e.g. [1](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/26d9/0fb0b8271e5cbcf44e11baaea10bce01b802.pdf), [2](http://www.gurobi.com/pdfs/benchmarks.pdf), [3](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09720510.2017.1395182).

You may choose your solver based on:

1. Previous experience with the solver
2. License availability (both solvers have a free academical license)
3. Solver documentation.

   - Both solvers are well-documented.

     - [CPLEX user guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.studio.help/pdf/usrcplex.pdf)
     - [Gurobi documentation](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/)
4. Community (to help you with questions related to the solver usage)

   - A good metric is the number of questions related to CPLEX and Gurobi here on Stack Overflow (from October 15):

     - CPLEX: 896 questions
     - Gurobi: 438 questions